# Use input field value from standard controller extension property

Tags: apex, visualforce, contact, extension

I am trying to get an input field value to reference a standard controller extension property.

Here is my controller extension:

```
public class LicenseActivationController {
    private final Contact contact;

    public LicenseActivationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        contact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public String activationID { get; set; }

    public String computerID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="LicenseActivationController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="License Activation">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!activationID}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!computerID}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Activate" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

As you can see, I am trying to use `activationID` and `computerID` properties in the corresponding `inputField`, but the error I get is:

> Error: Could not resolve the entity from  value
>   binding '{!activationID}'.  can only be used with
>   SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

How can I achieve extending the Contact controller and using properties inside the extension class like I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since those are not fields on an sObject you will need to use

```
<apex:inputText value="{!activationID}" />
```

If those are an Id to another object a trick is to create a property in the controller as a dummy sObject

```
public contact con {get; set;}
```

Then in your page use

```
<apex:inputField value="{!con.AccountId}"/>
```

for example to get the account lookup. Then in the controller simply reference `con.AccountId` to put where you really need it